# Como converter bloco de código em única linha?

Tags: html, editor-de-texto, notepad++

Preciso converter certos blocos de código em uma única linha.

Como posso fazer isso? Estou usando Notepad++

Comment: meo nem sabia que dava p/ fazer isso, que legal!

Comment: Grato pelos links HtmlCompressor e TextFixer que inclui esse conjunto de ferramentas adicionais:
[https://www.textfixer.com/tools/](https://www.textfixer.com/tools/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> para selecionar o bloco de código e depois <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> para unir as linhas.

A opção de juntas as linhas também está disponível, pelo menu: `Edit>Line Operations>Join lines`

Comment: Perfeito! É isso mesmo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 6):

Acredito que o melhor que você vai conseguir é fazer um "Replace" matando as quebras de linhas. Normalmente composta pelos caracteres de *carriage return* e *line feed* (`\r\n`).

[image: Replace Notepad++]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

O nome desse "recurso" é minimize/minify e você pode fazer isso usando aplicativos online.

São eles:

[HtmlCompressor](https://htmlcompressor.com/compressor/)

[TextFixer](http://www.textfixer.com/html/compress-html-compression.php)

A questão de deixar em 1 linha é irrelevante, porque a intenção é deixar o código "bagunçado".