# Ferramenta de formatação automática de código para Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

No meu dia a dia uso o Plugin TextFX para indentar meu código e fica bom o resultado.

Quando vou passar o código para outros programadores, eu uso o "Chrome Inspector", que tem um resultado mais completo e organizado. Eu gostaria de simplificar isso fazendo pelo próprio editor (NP++), de maneira automática como o TextFX faz.

- Gostaria que funcionasse de maneira similar ao inspetor do Chrome:

[image: Chrome inspector com código em uma linha só]

- Que resulta nisto:

[image: Resultado da formatação automática]

Existe alguma solução equivalente a esta para o Notepad++?

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser fora do escopo deste site.

Comment: Não sei se esse está sendo mantido: http://jsminnpp.sourceforge.net/ / Tem ferramentas online para isso, não é a mesma coisa que fazer no editor, mas já é algo: http://jsbeautifier.org/ - Só colar e mandar formatar. **Nota:** não é pra notepad++, mas esse último tem plugin pra vários outros editores caso venha a interessar no futuro.

Comment: Gente, como isso não pode ser do escopo do site? preciso disso pra programar ou não?   Que triste, onde eu posso fazer essa pergunta sem ofender ninguém?

Comment: E agora? devo apagar este post?

Comment: Bom, agora estou muito,  mas muito confusa mesmo...  isso nao e um tipo de identacao? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112800/elimina%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-palavras-repetidas-usando-o-notepad  ou isso ?http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81282/como-converter-bloco-de-c%C3%B3digo-em-%C3%BAnica-linha. Me parecem muito semelhantes. Me sentindo perdida.

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto eu sugeriria esperar um pouco antes de apagar, pq como os comentários continuam abertos, dá pra alguém dar alguma dica ainda. E dê uma espiada nos 2 links que eu indiquei acima, que são formatadores de código. Um deles pra NP++, inclusive. O outro não é pra NP++, mas funciona online, só colar o código lá que ele formata, e vc pode copiar de volta arrumadinho.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica de apagar, e sobre os links. Já estou testando eles!   você eh muito gentil!  você é  o the best mesmo!

Comment: Editei o post, vamos ver.

Comment: achei válida a pergunta

Comment: @DanielOmine :D

Comment: Acho que a pergunta está ok, algo relacionado ao Notepad++ entra nas [ferramentas comuns entre programadores](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Não sei se há algo para o notepad++, mas esse site é bem bacana e fica perfeito https://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html#ad-output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguindo as dicas do @Bacco,

O plugin para identação, que ficou mais próximo do padrão do chrome, foi o  jsminnpp.sourceforge.net (Ou seja o JSTools).
Vou passar a usa-lo mais !

Obrigada!